# IndexOf: how many vowels there are?

Tags: java

I need to have the code tell the user how many of the five vowels (a,e,i,o,u) are in the first string, as well as the second string. This is what I've worked up so far but I'm stuck in terms of how to print how many vowels there are total.

```
Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println( "Enter String 1: ");
    String s1=in.next();
    System.out.println( "Enter String 2: ");
    String s2=in.next();

   int a= s1.length();

   int b= s2.length();

   if (a<b)
   System.out.println( s2 + "is longer than " + s1);
   else if (b<a)
   System.out.println( s1 + " is longer than " + s2);
   else
   System.out.println(s1 + " and " + s2 + " are the same length.");

   int c=(s1.indexOf(('a')));
   int d=(s1.indexOf(('e')));
   int e=(s1.indexOf(('o')));
   int f=(s1.indexOf(('i')));
   int g=(s1.indexOf(('u')));



   if (c>=0)
   System.out.println( "AFFIRMATIVE FOR A");
   if (d>=0)
   System.out.println( "AFFIRMATIVE FOR E");
   if (e>=0)
   System.out.println( "AFFIRMAtive fOR O");
   if (f>=0)
   System.out.println( "AFFIRMATIVE for I");
   if (g>=0)
   System.out.println( "AFFIRMATIVE for U");
```

Comment: You need another variable, maybe called `totalVowels` or something, that you increment in each of the if statements. That way, by the time you are done with the if statements, you have counted up to the total amount.

Comment: Before I attempt to help, I would really suggest you use much more descriptive names for your variables. This is probably the main reason you are getting downvoted. Also, what is the exact question? Do you need to print how many instances of each vowel occurs?

Comment: @Seeker Thanks. I need to have a line that says something like, "(String 1) contains _ of the 5 vowels. That's the only line.

Comment: @0101001101000010 It sounds like you're right, but what would I put in with each of the if statements?

Comment: @J.Cole in each if statement just put `totalVowels++` under the `System.out.println` line. That way every time a vowel is in the string, the counter adds one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the guy above me said, you need to set a variable called totalVowels (or something like that) and increment it every time you encounter a vowel.

I'll take your own code (to make it a bit easier for you), and modify it a bit so you can see what I mean

```
       int totalVowels=0;

       int letterA=(s1.indexOf(('a')));
       int letterE=(s1.indexOf(('e')));
       int letterO=(s1.indexOf(('o')));
       int letterI=(s1.indexOf(('i')));
       int letterU=(s1.indexOf(('u')));

       if(letterA >=0){
          totalVowels ++; (this increments the total number of vowels)
       }
       if(letterE >=0){
          totalVowels ++; 
       }
       if(letterO >=0){
          totalVowels ++; 
       }
       if(letterI >=0){
          totalVowels ++; 
       }
       if(letterU >=0){
          totalVowels ++; 
       }

      System.out.println ("String1 contains" + totalVowels +" of the 5 vowels");
      totalVowels =0;
```

Now this is not really the optimal way of doing it, but it follows your code closely and should do the job.

Comment: This worked very well; however, I have another question. I need to have the user enter a "search key" that will search my strings for the value that the user enters. For example: Goodbye does contain by. This is what I've worked up so far, but I get an error message saying, "int cannot be converted to boolean." Any advice on how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
int count = s1.split("a").length - 1
```

Comment: Nice, except that you mean int rather than var. That's a different language :).

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code snippet.

```
int a=0,o=0,i=0,e=0,u=0;
for (int ii = 0;ii<s1.length();ii++)
{
    if (s1.charAt(ii)=='a')a++;
    if (s1.charAt(ii)=='o')o++;
    if (s1.charAt(ii)=='i')i++;
    if (s1.charAt(ii)=='u')u++;
    if (s1.charAt(ii)=='e')e++;
}
for (int ii = 0;ii<s2.length();ii++)
{
    if (s2.charAt(ii)=='a')a++;
    if (s2.charAt(ii)=='o')o++;
    if (s2.charAt(ii)=='i')i++;
    if (s2.charAt(ii)=='u')u++;
    if (s2.charAt(ii)=='e')e++;
}
int total = a+o+i+u+e;
System.out.println (total);
```